# Integral inequality (Cauchy-Schwarz)

Tags: analysis

Let $u\in \mathcal{C}^1[a,b]$ be such that $u(a)=u(b)=0$. Show that

$$\int_a^b u^2(x)dx\leq (b-a)^2\int_a^b (u')^2(x)dx$$

using the Schwarz's inequality.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate. But, I don't seem to find the same question which was asked earlier.

Comment: The condition $u(b)=0$ is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have  $|u(x)|\leq \int_a^x|u'(t)|dt\leq \sqrt{x-a}\sqrt{\int_a^b|u'(t)|^2}dt$ so 
$$u(x)^2\leq (x-a)\int_a^bu'(t)^2dt$$ and integrating 
$$\int_a^bu(x)^2dx\leq \frac{(b-a)^2}2\int_a^bu'(t)^2dt.$$